# Web-part search from Scopes to Result Sources

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, search-scope, result-source

I have a customized search web-part developed for SP2010 wich according to the source code is using Scopes in its query-string. The whole SP environment is now migrated to SP2013, and Scopes are no longer af part of 2010. Because of this change, the web-part does not longer display any search results.

Which solution is needed here? My tought was to create result sources in 2013, containing all the appropriate site-collections, and then change the source-code, the query string til hit the result source instead of the scope. Is this the correct way to do it?

[image]

So this is how the web-part looks like.

- The text field is a regulra search field
- Zip code is a managed property
- Town is a managed property
- And there are some more managed properties

The query string in the url-field ends with "...myPageWithWebPart.aspx?k=sharepoint?s=myScope"

So the data is not returned because the query-string is set to look after scope with name MyScope. So any idea how to change this to be working with 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SourceId parameter instead of the "s" parameter.

```
http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&sourceid='8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89'
```

You can get more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

Comment: That could be the solution. I did try it out with the source-id for my Local Result Source instead of the s=Scope parameter, and it did display results from the Local Result Source. So I have to change the string-query to use source-id instead of scopes ? :)

Comment: Yes, the s parameter is only for 2010.